# A maximal cardinality subset of n lattice points so that all points in the subset have distance at least 4

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

If we have some random set of $n$ lattice points what is the maximum cardinality of a subset in which all points have distance at least $4$ (or some other number).
I really hope the best bound is not the trivial $n/16$. I'm not asking for a proof that this bound is the best possible, just provide the best bound you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ll try to provide a framework for the question. Let $d$ be a fixed distance $d$ (equal to $4$ in our case).
A set $A’$ of lattice points we shall call *$d$-separated*, if any two distinct points of $B$ are placed at distance at least $d$. We are interested in a smallest $r=r(d)$  such  that any finite set $A$ of lattice points has a $d$-separated subset $B$ of size at least $|A|/r$. I guess Empy2 obtained a bound [$r\le 15$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3025233/71850) by constructing a coloring of $\Bbb Z^2$ into $15$ colors such that each monochromatic subset is $d$-separated. Indeed, in this case as $B$ we can chose a largest monochromatic subset of $A$, which imply $|B|\ge |A|/15$ .  Unfortunately, it can be easily shown that there is no such coloring in $14$ colors. (I’m going to write a proof later.) But this not imply that $r>14$, because a $d$-separated subset $B$ of $A$ may be chosen by different method. So there is sense to look for subsets $A$ of lattice points with the biggest ratio $|A|/|B|$, where $B$ is a maximal $d$-separated subset of $A$.

The following set has ratio $14$.

```
...
....
....
...
```

Are there subsets of lattice points with the bigger ratio?

Answer (score 1):

From the $n\times n$ array, the following gives about $ n^2/15$, or one point in every fifteen.

$$x(3,3)+y(-1,4)$$

Comment: Do you think it's possible to achieve $n^2/14$? That was actually a bound I was hoping for to solve a problem which led me to this question. The problem says that it's always possible to choose a subset of a set of unit circles having area $S$ so that the area of a chosen subset is at least $2S/9$. If you use a well-known result saying that for a figure of area $S$ it's always possible to set a coordinate system so that the figure contains at least $S$ lattice points it quickly becomes clear that a bound of $n^2/14$ would solve the problem.